# User defined function to return the firstname and lastname or any other option?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, user-defined-functions

In an SQL table, we have stored the `username` only, and that info is shown in a gridview in a web application in .net (Sharepoint application page)

We use this column for security reasons, add the user to the specific sharepoint group, etc. However we want to show the `firstname, lastname`.

I thought 2 options:

1. Create an UDF in .net, and inside it, query active directory? Then use the UDF in the stored procedure to return the firstname, lastname
2. In the gridview row databound event, take value of the username and do the same logic that we would implement in the UDF and then replace the cell contents

Is there any other option? What do you think about my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this should not be done in the database, so I would not do 1.

Option 2. looks more promising. However, I don't like how it's easy to miss this logic when someone is reading your code.

You could use something like model binding: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/model-binding/retrieving-data

You would replace `studentsGrid_GetData` with the function to look up user data.